Generic Device for storing sensitive information
I'm looking for a compact device which'd allow for storing arbitrary security info in the following format:

CollectionName: TheNameWhichMeansSomethingOnlyToMe
CollectionType: KeysForMyCustomProject



KeyName1: value
...
KeyNameN: value

Ideally I'd like to get the following:

The ability to configure sets of keys on per collection type, so when creating a new collection I can choose its type and get a predefined set of key (with or without values).
MFA (must support both fingerprints and manual input)
The ability to import keys/values from PC/mobile using BT or wire.
The ability to have some additional stats for they keys such as created/import date, date on which the key was used/exported. Would be also great to constrain the keys usage - ex. once a day or at least 2 hours since last usage.
The ability to generate keys using the most common algorithms, such as ECDSA/P-384


Hi Vladimir, welcome to Hardware Recs! Does this information need to actually be stored on an external device, or would a password safe stored on your internal device + an external authenticator (such as a Yubikey) be sufficient?

HI there and thank you. The info has to be stored on the actual device.

Are you just looking for a crypto wallet?

Kind of... But without any preset crypto networks. + The ability to generate keys.
